# Import uikit framework in webpack config error "UI.$ is not a function"

Tags: webpack-dev-server, getuikit

I use [Uikit](http://getuikit.com/) in react project it success to import **.less** with `resolve:{...}` but issue on import **uikit.js** and I change to `imports-loadaer` is It was the same

in webpack.config.js file

```
...
...
,
resolve: {
    root: [
        path.join(__dirname, 'theme/js'),
        path.join(__dirname, 'theme/less'),
        path.join(__dirname, 'theme/img'),
        path.join(__dirname, 'theme/timeline')
    ],
    extensions: ['','.js','.less','.jpg','.png','.svg']
},
plugins: [
    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
        $: "jquery",
        jQuery: "jquery",
        "window.jQuery": "jquery"
    })
],
module:{
    loaders:[
        {
            test:/\.js$/,
            loader:'babel',
            exclude:[nodeModulesPath],
            query: {presets: ['es2015', 'react']}
        },
        {
            test: /\.(eof|eot|ttf|woff(2)?)(\?[a-z0-9]+)?$/,
            loader: "url-loader?name=./bin/font/[name]-[hash].[ext]"
        },
        {
            test: /\.(png|jpg|svg)?$/,
            loader: "url-loader?limit=30000&name=./bin/img/[name]-[hash].[ext]"
        },
        {
            test: /\.(less|css)?$/,
            loader: 'style!css!less'
        }
    ]
},
```

and call in file

```
import 'gradient/uikit' <-- work !
import $ from 'jquery' <--- work !
import 'uikit.js' <--- issue "UI.$ is not a function"
```

Is there any way. please

Comment: I was trying this:

    import $ from 'jquery';
    import jQuery from 'jquery';
    window.$ = $;
    window.jQuery = jQuery;


But without success so far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

5 options:

## 1 (this worked fine)

This worked for me without the `UI.$` issue:

```
global.jQuery = require('jquery')
global.$ = global.jQuery
require('uikit')
window.UIkit.offcanvas.show('#sidebar')
```

## 2 (not working for me)

In your `main.js` file add the following:

```
import $ from 'jquery'
import jQuery from 'jquery'
window.$ = $
window.jQuery = jQuery
```

This must be executed BEFORE the `import UIkit from 'uikit'` line. So, add this before importing any component that may use uikit.

## 3 (not working for me)

You can also try the new npm module `uikit-loader`: https://www.npmjs.com/package/uikit-loader

## 4 (not working for me)

You can also try adding this to your `webpack` config file:

```
var webpack = require('webpack')

module.exports = {
  plugins: [
    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
      $: "jquery",
      jQuery: "jquery",
      "window.jQuery": "jquery",
      "window.$": "jquery"
    })
  ]
}
```

## 5 (not working for me)

You can try the `webpack` `imports-loader`: https://www.npmjs.com/package/imports-loader